# How can I PHPUnit test a Controller_Plugin that uses a Redirector helper to redirect?

Tags: php, zend-framework, phpunit

I can't work this out.

```
    $this->_request->setBasePath('http://localhost/');
    $this->_request->setModuleKey('admin');
    $this->_request->setControllerKey('controller-page');
    $this->_request->setActionKey('index');

    $this->_sslRedirect->preDispatch($this->_request);

    $this->assertRedirectRegex('/https:/');
```

In my controller plugin preDispatch() may or may not do a redirect to SSL. This works in the browser, however I'm not able to write a test for it. The test fails, like so:

```
Failed asserting response redirects to URL MATCHING "/https:/"

/srv/app/zend/library/Zend/Test/PHPUnit/Constraint/Redirect.php:190
/srv/app/zend/library/Zend/Test/PHPUnit/ControllerTestCase.php:764
/srv/app/www/tests/lib/Saffron/Controller/Plugin/SslRedirectTest.php:36
/usr/bin/phpunit:46
```

I also tried with a $this->dispatch() inside the Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase immediately after the preDispatch() line, but for some reason this caused a Error 404 Not Found...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If this is your unit test code, I'm not seeing anything mocked up, and I'm completely sure I understand why this is being implemented this way (if the goal is to force an https connection)

I think theres an issue with these two lines.

```
$this->_sslRedirect->preDispatch($this->_request);
$this->assertRedirectRegex('/https:/');
```

If you could post the complete action you are testing, and the complete unit test you are using to test it, it would help.